# Git: Is there a way to change the local repository for a remote repo?

Tags: git

I'm currently creating a web server using AWS, and as a test, I made a simple server in a folder. I initialized a git repo and then pushed to the remote repo, where my pipeline detected a change and redeployed the server with the new files. In a different folder, I have stored the server I actually want to use. When I initialize a git repo in the directory and set the remote's origin to the same as the other folder's remote's origin, no branches are detected when I run `git branch -a`. I guess I understand why this shouldn't be allowed, because the files weren't being tracked in the first place, but I'm wondering if there's a way I can remove the old commit history (which I found how to do in another post) and use this folder as the source of truth.

I can quite easily work around this by just copying all the files over, deleting the old commit history, and then pushing again, but I'm just curious if this other method is feasible.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "remote repo", when you're actually *using* Git. There is only one repository and it's local. Using commands like `git fetch` or `git push`, you *copy commits* from or to some other repository, using your local repository as the source or sink, so sometimes Git grudgingly acknowledges the existence of some other repository (or at least *commits* in what must therefore be a repository), but that's as close as Git ever gets to that.

Comment: I think that your process does not make much sense. git is for keeping change history and spread it around. In your case you create new disconnected histories with *init* and try to make them history heads for what? Usually it is just the opposite, there is one 'origin' repo which gets *cloned*, updated and updates are *pushed* into it.

Comment: @Serge I suspected so. I realized that what I wanted didn't quite make sense. Thanks for the the clarification